# Writing Docs for overloaded Java functions

Tags: java, android, documentation

Im writing custom docs for some java methods, and some of them are overloaded functions.

I want to make the documentation as small and easy to understand as possible. Heres an example of the functions im overloading.

```
public void overload(String abc);

public void overload(String abc, OverloadHandler handler);
```

There are several functions like this, with identical parameters, bar the fact that one call handles errors itself, and the other can be passed a handler so the caller can handle the errors personally (its for an SDK, Android SDK if that matters).

How can i easily show that a developer can add another parameter on the end, but not have to have a massive piece of documentation for each function individually. Something along the lines of "original function here, also you can add an extra OverloadHandler parameter to the end to handle errors if you want"

So my question is, whats the best practice for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
/** This function forwards to {@link #overload(String,OverloadHandler) overload} 
 *  with a default handler.
 */
```